# AudioRecord extract amplitude from ShortArray

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder, android-audiorecord

I'm using

```
val data = ShortArray(minBuffer)
audioRecord.read(data, 0, minBuffer)
```

I have seen few solutions of how to extract amplitude from `ByteArray`, but how to do it with `ShortArray`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var sum = 0L
for (i in 0 until minBufferSize step 2) {
  sum += abs(data[i].toInt())
}

amplitude = (sum / (minBufferSize / 8)).toInt()
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)